# how to save state of each item in recycleview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-listview, android-adapter

Here is the structure of the application

Main Activity --> movies fragment/series fragment --> recycle view via custom adapter --> card view XML layout

the main activity dynamically selects the fragments based on the button selection.
the movies/series fragments use the adapter to initialize the recycler view.
the adapter uses an XML card view layout for each item which also contains the like and dislike radio buttons.

so here is my question, how do I save the state of the like and dislike radio buttons? when switching between pages(fragments)?

I've attached an image of the application for more context

[image]

every time I click movies or series button the fragments rerenders and loses all information.

do I save the state in the main activity? the movies fragment? or in the adapter? whats the correct approach?

Comment: are you using a api or hardcoded data

Comment: For now I'm using hard-coded data.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and faster solution is shareprefs for each item ID.
But this is not recommended for real-world projects
Either you can use Room for the local database or you can update every like or unlike on the server and then fetch your data from the server when fragment recreates. all solution depends on your use case. factors to keep in mind is size of data-list and update frequency of your data.

Comment: So I'm building a demo to learn android dev, and I wanted to see how to save data locally. I tried to save the state of the fragment and restore it via the saved instance but didn't work. This is why I'm going to look at the room approach. However, as you mentioned, using API makes more sense and is how it should be implemented for a real-world app. I will try both approaches for learning purposes and share my findings. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't save state like this because hard coded object will be destroyed and created on app exit and start. I think best approach will be to use [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) database
2. Add a boolean(Like /disliked to your data class.
3. Use [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) database to save your data in storage.

Comment: I didn't realize that hardcoded objects will be destroyed upon restart. I took a look at the documentation for the room database and it seems like the correct approach. I'm going to give it a try and implemented it. Will share the results as soon as it finished. Thanks for leading me to this approach.